# How can I reduce Jquery code with the same functionality, but different events

Tags: jquery, events, dry

How can I reduce this code? They do the same, that is disable a button if there is no value in a any of the two selects.

```
    //Evento de submenu Canal
    $(document).on('change','select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"]',function(){
        if (($('select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '') || ($('select[name="canalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '')) {
            $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", true);
        } else{
            $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });

    //Evento de submenu Canal
    $(document).on('change','select[name="canalSubMenu"]', function(){

        if (($('select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '') || ($('select[name="canalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '')) {
            $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", true);
        } else{
            $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I assume the code in both functions is identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use css's comma separator to add the other selector in.

```
//Evento de submenu Canal
$(document).on('change','select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"], select[name="canalSubMenu"]',function(){
    if (($('select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '') || ($('select[name="canalSubMenu"]').children("option:selected").val() == '')) {
        $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", true);
    } else{
        $('#new-usuario-registrar-canal').attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do the same, but it didn't work for me. But now I see that I was putting two quotation marks between every name. Like this:

       $(document).on('change', 'select[name="grupoCanalSubMenu"]', 'select[name="canalSubMenu"]', function() {